# Calling external contract from a contract in same block

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Please check this code:

```
contract Token is StandardToken {  
  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value)  public returns (bool success) {
      return super.transfer(_to, _value);
    }
}

contract CrowdSale { 
  token = Token(:address)
  function buyToken() payable {
    token.transfer(beneficiary,tokenAmount); // OPERATION A
    anotherAddress.transfer(msg.value); // OPERATION B
  }
}
```

In the above example, will OPERATION A and OPERATION B be called in same block?

Or buyToken will be called which calls token.transfer and wait till it is mined and then anotherAddress.transfer is called in next block once first is mined?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistaken about some concepts here. A block registers transactions.

The transaction is the fact of calling a method, deploying a contract, "moving the state of a contract".

In simple words : yes, a contract called by another contract will be called in the same block as the **block won't contain the instructions** itself **but the result of the transaction** .

In order to be able to give the result of a transaction, by logic, the whole instructions need to be processed on same block, otherwise the miner couldn't determine if the transaction is valid and then register it into the block.